# Custom function for linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to calculate a status based on some threshold variables for a linq to SQL IQueryable Entity.

My entity 
contains two properties

```
public decimal Threshold { get; set; }
public decimal Value{ get; set; }
```

Now there are other properties for which I am using automapper for projection. Essentially

There is a property for the "response" which takes in the "threshold" and "value" to calculate the "status".

I ended up writing a custom Expression Func.

```
 Expression<Func<EntityModel, string>> GetSeverity(EntityModel entity)
        {


            var fraction = (double)entity.Value / (double)entity.Threshold;

            var red = nameof(Severity.Red);

            var amber = nameof(Severity.Amber);

            var green = nameof(Severity.Green);

            if (fraction > 1)
            {
                return t => red;
            }

            if (fraction >= 0.75 && fraction < 1)
            {
                return t => amber;
            }

            return t => green;
        }
```

Severity is just an enum.

Now Maybe my usage of a func expression is incorrect

```
CreateMap<EntityModel, ResponseModel>()
           .ForMember(d => d.Severity,e => e.MapFrom(d => GetSeverity(d)));
```

I end up getting the exception

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 
>   'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: That error indicates an issue with your query, not with the mapping code.

Comment: What do I need to change in order to fix the "t => Severity" ?

Comment: I don't think you need to change anything with that.  You need to show the query that you are running and then mapping as I believe the error is in the query itself.

Comment: You do have an issue in your code though.  If fraction is exactly equal to 1 it return green, which I'm guessing you actually want amber.

Comment: yeah true that...fixed the logic...but yeah still struck with the first problem.

Comment: Get rid of the the method and place its contents inside the MapFrom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why does this have to be a mapped function? Why not pull down the values needed and then project into a enitity as needed at runtime? Such as (pseudo code)

```
var currentValues = 
MyTable.GetValues()
       .ToList()        // Gets the values from the db and makes them IEnumerable
       .Select(itm => new {
                              Status = DetermineStatus( … ), // "Red" | "Yellow" ...
                              itm
                          }
               )
       .ToList();
...
private string DetermineStatus(...variables here....);
```

---

Or better define a partial class from your model with a new property that returns status as a calculated property?

```
 partial class MyDBItem
 {
     public string Status { get { return DetermineStatus( … ); } }
 }
```